# Dynamically aligned multi-dimensional array is not regarded as aligned by the GCC compiler

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-alignment

I am new to loop vectorization. But I couldn't find answers to my simple task by searching the internet for several days.

I have a 2-D array which has 4 doubles in the first dimension. I want to vectorize this 4 elements. If I use static array gas[32768][4] in the code below, and compile the code with

> g++ -O2 -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=7 stack.cpp

it shows

> vect_model_load_cost: aligned.

for the bottom k loop. However, if I use dynamic array as shown below, it shows

> Vectorizing an unaligned access

But, I think my dynamic array is indeed aligned.
I wonder how to force the compiler to know that the array is indeed aligned.

I have also tried array of structure instead of 2-D array. Again, if it is a static array, it is OK.
But if it is a dynamically assigned array of structure using >new, the compiler won't recognize the alignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <new>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   clock_t t;
   double temp[4];
   int ng=32768;
   int i, j, k;

   double **gas;
   gas = (double **)memalign(__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__,32768*sizeof(double*));
   gas[0] = (double *)memalign(__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__,32768*4*sizeof(double));
   for (i=0; i<32768; i++){
     gas[i] = (double *)((unsigned char *)gas[0] + i*4*sizeof(double));
   }

/*
 replace above 7 lines with static assignment: double gas[32768][4]; then the compiler recoganize that the data are aligned
*/

   for (i=0; i<ng; i++){
     for (k=0; k<4; k++){
       gas[i][k]=i*1.0;
     }
   }
   for (j=0; j<10000; j++){
     for (k=0; k<4; k++){
        temp[k]=gas[j][k];
        temp[k]+=gas[j+1][k];
        temp[k]+=gas[j+2][k];
        temp[k]+=gas[j+13][k];
        temp[k]+=gas[j+14][k];
        temp[k]+=gas[j+15][k];
        temp[k]+=gas[j+16][k];
     }
   }
    std::cout<<temp[0]<<" "<<temp[1]<<" "<<temp[2]<<" "<<temp[3]<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why `(unsigned char *)gas[0] + i*4*sizeof(double)` and not just `gas[0] + i*4` ?

Comment: Very important: what platform are you compiling for?

Comment: Have you try C++11: `struct array4 { alignas(16) double a[4];}; std::vector<array4> gas(32768);` ?

Comment: You do realize that the actual process of doing `gas[i][k]` is very different when it's going through 2 pointers, than when you did `double gas[32768][4]` ?

Comment: j_kubik:I have double array so that I need to times size of double. I compile it for linux.

Comment: Matt McNabb: Yes, I realize that they are very different. But I want to dynamically assign the array in the real progam

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use __builtin_assume_aligned? See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html . You might be able to use that to tell the compiler that your pointer is sufficiently aligned. E.g something like

```
double *tmp = memalign (16, some_size);
double *ptr = __builtin_assume_aligned(tmp, 16);
// Now *ptr points to tmp and the compiler should be able to assume that *ptr 
// is 16 byte aligned.
```